# Surface area lost from drilling a hole in an ellipsoid

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, conic-sections, intersection-theory

I am given an ellipsoid of known dimensions. I am trying to figure out what the surface area lost would be if a hole were drilled in it at a non-perpendicular angle (since obviously, if the angle is 90 degrees, area lost = area of circle).

Any advice on how I can approach this problem? The dimensions that would be provided would be the axes of the ellipsoid, the angle at which the hole is drilled, and the width/radius of the cylinder whose intersection would cause the hole.

Comment: First, the area lost at 90° should not be the area of a circle, but rather of the section of the ellipsoid intercepted by a cylinder. You would have to state the problem a finding the intersection border, then computing the surface area. This will likely require an integral. When you say the dimensions are known, do you mean the lengths of the axes or just the number of dimension (i.e. is it a 3D or 4D ellipsoid?).

Comment: Is the hole drilled through the center of the ellipsoid? You would also need the direction vector of the axis of the hole. And even at $90^\circ$, the area would not be a circle.

Comment: "Non-perpendicular angle" with respect to what?